# How specify the behaviour of SpringClassRule/SpringMethodRule for a specific @Test?

Tags: spring, junit, junit4, spring-test

I am working with Spring `4.3.1.RELEASE` and I have the following about testing:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContextConfig.class})
@Transactional
public class PersonaJdbcRepositoryTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE= new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired
    private PersonaRepository personaJdbcRepository;

    private final Persona persona;

    public PersonaJdbcRepositoryTest(Persona persona){
        this.persona = persona;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Persona[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Persona[][] {
            {PersonaFactory.crearPersona01()},
            {PersonaFactory.crearPersona02()},
            {PersonaFactory.crearPersona03()},
            {PersonaFactory.crearPersona04()},
            {PersonaFactory.crearPersonaMix()}
        });
    }

    @Test
    @Sql(scripts={"classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/h2/h2-elimination-script.sql"})
    public void saveOneTest(){
        Persona personaSaveOne = personaJdbcRepository.saveOne(persona);
        Persona personaFindOne = personaJdbcRepository.findOne(personaSaveOne.getId());
        assertEquals(personaFindOne, personaSaveOne);
    }


    @Test
    public void findOneTest(){
        Persona personaFindOne = personaJdbcRepository.findOne(persona.getId());
        assertEquals(personaFindOne, persona);
    }

    @Test
    public void findAllTest(){
        Collection<Persona> personas = PersonaFactory.crearPersonas();
        Collection<Persona> personasFindAll = personaJdbcRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(personas.size(), personasFindAll.size());

    }

}
```

I can confirm that each `@Test` is executed and pass N times (in this case 5) according with `data()`.

My requirement is that: I only need one execution of the `findAllTest()` method. I mean, it is executed 4 times unnecessarily. Even more when it does not use the `persona` object.

Therefore *is possible* indicate through `SpringClassRule/SpringMethodRule` that a `@Test` method just works once? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to indicate through `SpringClassRule/SpringMethodRule` that a `@Test` method just runs once?

No. That is not possible.

The behavior you are experiencing has nothing to do with Spring.

It is the `Parameterized` runner that controls how many times a test method is executed.

If you don't want a test method to be parameterized, simply move it to a different test class that does not use the `Parameterized` runner.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks by the reply. Even when is not related with Spring, If a JIRA request is created, would be added that feature through Spring? or has no sense? Let me know to proceed or not.

Comment: No, it does not make sense to request this in Spring simply because of the fact that it is literally impossible for Spring to do anything about it.

Comment: Should create an `issue` in `JUnit` **5** to ask for that feature? Something like `@Test(parameterized=false)`, therefore when the Test class is executed that Test method just executed once (it should not be affected by `@Parameters`) . Has sense?

Comment: No need to create a new issue. We already have a dedicated issue for parameterized tests in JUnit 5: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/14